# Downloading multiple files from FTP site using PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, ftp, webclient, ftpwebrequest

I want to download multiple files from FTP using PowerShell 5.0 with Windows 7. The script I wrote works fine for a single file but does not work for multiple files with wildcard character. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?
When I execute the script , I got an error stating:

```
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."At 
C:\Users\Documents\Powershell_Script\write-demo7.ps1:49 char:9
+         $webclient.DownloadFile($fileuri, $localfilename
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

I searched the internet and could not find my answer.
Please help...
Here is my script:

```
function Get-FtpDir ($url,$credentials)
{
    $request = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $request.Credentials = $credentials
    $request.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::ListDirectory
    $response = $request.GetResponse()
    $reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $response.GetResponseStream()
    $readline = $reader.ReadLine()
    $output = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
    while ($readline -ne $null)
    {
        $output.Add($readline)
        $readline = $reader.ReadLine()
    }
    $reader.Close()
    $response.Close()
    $output
}

$server = "msftran.tran.com"
$user = "myusername"
$pass = "mypassword"
$invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value
$localpath = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path
$YestDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2).ToString('yyMMdd') 
$remotefilepath = "/"
$localfilename = "C:\Users\database\Nightly_Files\file*.nightly.out."+$YestDate
$localfilelocation = "$localfilename"
$uri = New-Object System.Uri(“ftp://$server/$remotefilepath”)

#List of all files on FTP-Server
$files = Get-FTPDir $uri -credentials (New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $pass))

foreach ($file in $files)
{    
   if ($file -eq "file1.nightly.out.$YestDate" -or 
       $file -eq "file2.nightly.out."+$YestDate -or
       $file -eq "file3.nightly.out."+$YestDate)
     {
        $file        
        $fileuri = New-Object System.Uri(“ftp://$server/$remotefilepath/$file”)               
        $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient        
        $webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $pass)
        $webclient.DownloadFile($fileuri, $localfilelocation       
        )
        
     }
    
}
echo 'download completed'
```

Comment: See also [Download files whose name contains a specific string from an FTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64754385/850848).

Answer (score 1):

How would `DownloadFile` know what to do with your asterisk? And you have that information already in the `$file` variable. Instead of full local file name, begin only with the path to the folder:

```
$localfolder = "C:\Users\database\Nightly_Files\"
```

You could also do well with one `if` instead of three using `-like`operator:

```
if ($file -like "file[1-3].nightly.out.$YestDate")
```

And launch the download concatenating local path with the file name:

```
$webclient.DownloadFile($fileuri, "$localfolder$file")
```